# how to add reminders / reminders kind notifications which reminds the user once set in c#/xaml metro app?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

hi i am developing a c#/xaml metro app, i want to set reminders in my app .

1)how to set a reminder in c#/xaml metro app ??

2)reminders kind notifications which will remind the user at that particluar time?

3)alternative ways to adding reminders to c#/xaml metro app ??

i want to make it user specific , if the user sets the reminder he should get a notification even if my app is running or not running.

Please let me know how can i do this ,  help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [Scheduled Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465454.aspx) would work for you here.

Check out the [official Windows SDK sample on scheduled notifications](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/scheduled-notifications-da477093) and I also have [a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/08/08/windows-8-notifications-scheduled-notifications.aspx) that may be helpful.